# Why does glob fail when I call my function twice?

Tags: perl, glob

I have the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub test {

        my $glob = glob("test?pl");
        print "glob [$glob]\n";
        $glob = glob("test?pl");
        print "glob [$glob]\n";
}

test();
test();
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
glob [test.pl]

glob [test.pl]

Use of uninitialized value $glob in concatenation (.) or string at ./test.pl line 9.

glob []

Use of uninitialized value $glob in concatenation (.) or string at ./test.pl line 11.

glob []
```

Why is `glob` failing the second time I call the `test` function? I'm using Perl 5.14.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `glob`'s [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

> In scalar context, `glob` iterates through such filename expansions, returning undef when the list is exhausted.

In other words, when you call `glob` is in scalar context, it returns the first expansion. The second call to that same `glob` instance returns the second expansion, and so on. When all expansions have been returned, `glob` returns `undef` to indicate this.

To get all expansions at once:

```
my @expansions = glob($glob);
```

To get all expansions, one at a time:

```
while (defined( my $expansion = glob($glob) )) {
   ...
}
```

To get the first expansion and ignore the rest:

```
my ($expansion) = glob($glob);
```